# How to Retrieve a Custom Event Name in Azure Stream Analytics

Tags: sql, azure, azure-stream-analytics, custom-events

I created a custom event that is tracked by Azure Application Insights. It has a few custom data properties I am able to successfully track, as well as 2 custom event properties of interest (one of which I cannot display).

The one I cannot successfully query is the event name. I'm trying to reference it in the query by using event.name, but it's returning null for all records, even though I know for sure the names are not actually null.

[image: Sample input json file with name property shown]

[image: More proof that name isn't supposed to be null]

[image: Current query. All non-circled properties are displaying]

If anyone knows the proper way to query the custom event's name, please let me know! I can't find it on: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-export-data-model

Comment: Have you tried using CROSS APPLY? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/reference/apply-azure-stream-analytics?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: I'm not sure how I would combine what I already have with a cross apply. Would I query the event name from the input or the first query? @SidRamadoss

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is name is in an array, so event.name returns NULL since it doesn't exist.

Will you always have only 1 name in this array?
If so the following query will extract that value:

```
SELECT GetRecordPropertyValue(GetArrayElement(event, 0),'name')  as eventName from input
```

If you have various names, the query will depend of the logic (hence the suggestion to use CROSS APPLY).